# jquery call function after load html content

Tags: jquery, function, load

Imagine i have 2 html files

index.html

```
<html>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script>
        $("#content").load("productos.html");
        $("#footer").load("pie.html");
    </script>
</html>
```

productos_main.html

```
<html>
...
<div id="prod_fabricantes" class="optbar">fabricantes</div>
<div id="prod_industria" class="optbar">industria</div>
<div id="prod_header"></div>
<div id="prod_mainframe"></div>
...
<script>
$('#prod_fabricantes').live('click', function() {
    document.title = '..:: TITLLE :: Productos :: Fabricantes';
    $("#prod_header,#prod_mainframe").empty();
    $("prod_header").text("Text for Fabricantes's section");
    $('#prod_mainframe').load("prod_fabricantes.html");

});
$('#prod_industria').live('click', function() {
    document.title = '..:: TITLLE :: Productos :: Industria';
    $("#prod_header,#prod_mainframe").empty();
    $("prod_header").text("Text for Industria's section");
    $('#prod_mainframe').load("prod_industria.html");

});
</script>
</html>
```

pie.html

```
<html>
<div id="map syte">
<table class="table_site">
<tr>
<td id="st_fab" class="topsite">Fabricantes</td>
<td id="st_ind" class="topsite">Industria</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$('#st_fab').live('click', function(){
    $('#content').empty();
    document.title = '..:: DIELECSUR S.L :: Productos :: Fabricantes';
    $("#content").load("productos_main.html");
    $("#prod_header,#prod_mainframe").empty();
    $("prod_header").text("Text for Fabricantes's section");
    $('#prod_mainframe').load("prod_fabricantes.html");
});
$('#st_ind').live('click', function(){
    $('#content').empty();
    document.title = '..:: DIELECSUR S.L :: Productos :: Idustria';
    $("#content").load("productos_main.html");
    $("#prod_header,#prod_mainframe").empty();
    $("prod_header").text("Text for Industria's section");
    $('#prod_mainframe').load("prod_industria.html");
});
...
</html>
```

I have problems to load content using site map in footer section.
events onclick for footer options
1.click on `#st_fab`
2.it would load productos_main.html into `#content` div
3.if would execute functions below `$('#st_fab').live('click', function() { ... });`

error

it only load productos_main.html into #content div

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#content").load("productos.html", function() {
  $("#footer").load("pie.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted putting the .load event into function and within using:

```
function mainFrameLoad(strHTMLFile){
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#prod_mainframe').load(strHTMLFile);
    });
 }
```